# why is openpyxl cell font size returning none?

Tags: python, openpyxl, font-size

I am trying to get font sizes of cells from an excel sheet.
However, many of the files that I read has 'None' for the cell font size, and this applies to the entire sheet. I have checked that all of these cells have text in them.
This is a sample output for a `cell.font`:

```
<openpyxl.styles.fonts.Font object>
Parameters:
name='Asap', charset=None, family=None, b=False, i=False, strike=None, outline=None, shadow=None, condense=None, color=None, extend=None, sz=None, u=None, vertAlign=None, scheme=None
```

When this happens, can I assume the entire sheet has the same font size? Or is it using some default size and How can I get the default size?

Comment: Font objects don't have name attributes so something must have added this. Please include all relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

It's not unlikely that the module has the limitation. Sometimes you can get a work around with module `win32com` and its direct access to Excel's bowels.

Something like this:

```
import win32com.client

app = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
cell = app.ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
print(cell.Font.Size) # Output: 10.0
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.cellformat.font

But I'm afraid it works on Windows only.

Answer (score 0):

As of the latest openpyxl, you can do `cell.font.size` to retrieve the size. This works when all cells have the same font size and this also works on cells part of a merged range. When you view the `Font` object it does not show the size parameter despite being a valid parameter of `Font()`. If you view the parameters list of other objects you will also notice some valid parameters missing.